# TypeError: rules.map is not a function - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

Trying to run an unit test for the following:
Here is a piece of the code :

```
    renderAdvancedColumns = () => {
let rules = this.props.selectedFormJSON ? this.props.selectedFormJSON.FORM_RULE : [];
let inner = [];

if(rules.length !== 0) {
  inner = rules.map((rule, i) => { //LINE GIVING ERROR
    return (
      <div className={i===0? 'settings-field first-form-field' : 'settings-field'}>
      <div className='settings-label'>
        {rule.Event}
        <div 
          className={this.props.selectedFormJSON.FORM_RULE[i].FORM_OPERATION.HttpMethod !== 'POST' && 
            this.props.selectedFormJSON.FORM_RULE[i].FORM_OPERATION.HttpMethod !== 'PATCH' ? 
            'tran-button specify-body-button disabled' : 'tran-button specify-body-button'} 
          disabled={this.props.selectedFormJSON.FORM_RULE[i].FORM_OPERATION.HttpMethod === 'GET'}
          onClick={()=>{this.setState({specifyBodyModalOpen: true})}}>
          Specify Body
        </div>
      </div>
      <input className='settings-input' value={this.props.selectedFormJSON.FORM_RULE[i].FORM_OPERATION.Endpoint || ''} onChange={(e) => {this.updateFORMOPERATION(i, 'Endpoint', e.target.value)}} />
```

I usually start my testing files and make sure they all props render correctly. But unsure why this is blocking : **inner = rules.map((rule, i) => {**

Here is how i declare this.props

```
const baseProps = {
 selectedFormJSON :{
  Subform:{},
 SubformFilter:{},
 OverlayMapper:{},
 Name:{},
 Form_UID:{},
 FORM_RULE:{
 FORM_OPERATION:{
 Endpoint:{},
 HttpMethod:{},
 },
},


  Describe('FormSettings ', () => {
 let wrapper;
 let tree;

 it('should render using all of the props', () => {  
tree = renderer.create(<BrowserRouter><FormSettings {...baseProps} /> 
 </BrowserRouter>)
let treeJson = tree.toJSON()
expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
tree.unmount()
});
```

Comment: `this.props.selectedFormJSON.FORM_RULE`  is an object, `.map()` works only with arrays

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert an object to an array of arrays with 0 element `key` and 1 `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectedFormJSON.FORM_RULE is an object

You cannot use map on an object.

Comment: How could I fix, substitute map with something else ?